# Why OrderBy does not sort the data?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, linq

I want to group and sort data, but OrderBy function is not working as it should, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong

Code:

```
var data = new List<PreparedData>() {
  new PreparedData {
    IsGroup = false,
    Service = "Number 5",
    Name = "Banana",
    SomeValue = 5,
  },
  new PreparedData {
    IsGroup = false,
    Service = "Number 5",
    Name = "Apple",
    SomeValue = 5,
  },
  new PreparedData {
    IsGroup = false,
    Service = "Number 3",
    Name = "Apple",
    SomeValue = 5,
  },
  new PreparedData {
    IsGroup = false,
    Service = "Number 3",
    Name = "Blueberry",
    SomeValue = 9,
  },
  new PreparedData {
    IsGroup = true,
    Service = "Number 9",
    Name = "Garlic",
    SomeValue = 7,
  }
}


var groupedAndSortedData = data.GroupBy(x => x.IsGroup).Select(isGroup => new FruitViewData 
  {
    IsGroup = isGroup.Key,
    FruitData = isGroup.GroupBy(s => s.Service).Select(service => new FruitServiceData 
    {
      Service = service.OrderBy(z => z.Service).First().Service,
      FruitTypeData = service.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(fruitType => new FruitTypeData 
      {
        Name = fruitType.Name,
        SomeValue = fruitType.SomeValue
      }  
    }
  }
```

At the end I get:

```
[
  {
    IsGroup: false
    FruitData: [
      {
        Service: "Number 5",
        FruitTypeData: [
          {
            Name: "Banana",
            SomeValue = 5,
          },
          { 
            Name: "Apple",
            SomeValue = 5,
          },
        ] 
      },
      {
        Service: "Number 3",
        FruitTypeData: [
          {
            Name: "Apple",
            SomeValue = 5,
          },
          { 
            Name: "Blueberry",
            SomeValue = 9,
          },
        ] 
    ]
  },
  {
    IsGroup: true
    FruitData: [
      {
        Service: "Number 9",
        FruitTypeData: [
          {
            Name: "Garlic",
            SomeValue = 9,
          }
        ] 
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

But I would like to get sorted data like:

```
[
  {
    IsGroup: false
    FruitData: [
      {
        Service: "Number 3",
        FruitTypeData: [
          {
            Name: "Apple",
            SomeValue = 5,
          },
          { 
            Name: "Blueberry",
            SomeValue = 9,
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        Service: "Number 5",
        FruitTypeData: [
          {
            Name: "Apple",
            SomeValue = 5,
          },
          { 
            Name: "Banana",
            SomeValue = 5,
          },
        ] 
      }, 
    ]
  },
  {
    IsGroup: true
    FruitData: [
      {
        Service: "Number 9",
        FruitTypeData: [
          {
            Name: "Garlic",
            SomeValue = 9,
          }
        ] 
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

I tried to sort it in a different way like for example using the foreach loop after groupedAndSortedData and add OrderBy function to every iteration but also without satisfactory effect

What should I change to get the expected result?

Comment: When you group nothing is ordered. Then you take the key in the original order..

Comment: The code shown *does not* produce result you claim it does - fruits should be sorted by name (unlike what you've shown). Please make sure to provide real [mcve] and doublecheck your data. Also clarify what exactly you don't like in the data as there is a lot to compare. While [edit] the post fix all errors in the C# code too - it missing way to many braces and semicolons.

Comment: And clarify if SQL tag is actually related to the question - possibly should be linq-to-sql instead or removed altogether.

Comment: a) always sort before grouping: orderby(outergroup).thenby(nextgroup).... b) note that you are not sorting the data but constructing new data from fields of the old ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to order the `FruitData` results:

```
var groupedAndSortedData = data.GroupBy(x => x.IsGroup).Select(isGroup => new FruitViewData
{
    IsGroup = isGroup.Key,
    FruitData = isGroup.GroupBy(s => s.Service).Select(service => new FruitServiceData
    {
        Service = service.OrderBy(z => z.Service).First().Service,
        FruitTypeData = service.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(fruitType => new FruitTypeData
        {
            Name = fruitType.Name,
            SomeValue = fruitType.SomeValue
        })
    }).OrderBy(fd => fd.Service) //This here
});
```

Notice the `.OrderBy(fd => fd.Service)` method call.